# Delphi tmediaplayer don't play mp3 file with "strange" cover image embedded

Tags: image, delphi, mp3, tmediaplayer

I have developed a mp3 player with Delphi (XE) using the BASS library.

Due to certain reasons, I want to remove the BASS libraries and want to use the `TMediaPlayer` component in Delphi (also want to "move" the project to Delphi 10 Seattle).

Now I found out that some of my mp3 files have a "strange" jpg image embedded.

Means, that the Delphi components run into an error due to the image.

With long time debugging I can say the following:

```
try
  mplMain.FileName := CurrentSong;

  progbSong.Max := mplMain.Duration;
  lblDuration.Text := DurationToString(mplMain.Duration);
  PlayClick(Self);

except
  on E: Exception do
  begin
    FMX.Dialogs.MessageDlg('Cannot play song: ' + CurrentSong + #10 + #13 +
                           'Reason: ' + E.Message,
                           TMsgDlgType.mtWarning, [TMsgDlgBtn.mbOK], 0,
      procedure(const AResult: TModalResult)
      begin
        MediaNext;
      end
    );
  end;
end;
```

This line:

```
mplMain.FileName := CurrentSong;
```

causes the problem.

Diving deeper in debugging it comes to here:

`FMX.Media` library:

```
procedure TMediaPlayer.SetFilename(const Value: String);
  ...
  FMedia := TMediaCodecManager.CreateFromFile(FFileName);
  ...
```

At the end it ends up in `FMX.Media.Win`:

```
constructor TWindowsMedia.Create(const AFileName: string);
  ...
  HR := FGraphBuilder.RenderFile(PChar(AFileName), nil);
  ...
```

When the line

```
HR := FGraphBuilder.RenderFile(PChar(AFileName), nil);
```

is called, in debug mode, the program just returns to the IDE.

In runtime mode, nothing happens. No error message, just "nothing".

As you can see, I wrapped the related line into a `try...except` block, but no error is raised. The program/player doesn't continue.

That's very bad for me, because I wanted to catch this "special case" and log the affected mp3 files to a logfile so that I can change the embedded image.

I found out that it is only caused by some images. Maybe they are "somehow corrupt", but shown in all other players.

When I remove the image and embed a "new" one and save the file, everything is fine and the `TMediaPlayer` can play the file.

How can I catch this certain kind of "error" to get the list of affected files?

Comment: Cannot reproduce with MP3 file with a JPG artwork on Windows 7. Could you share that specific file?

Comment: I'm on Windows 7 too. :-)
You can download the file here:
http://mschlereth.de/stuff/dl/05%20-%20Fan%20Tong%20Zhou%20-%20Wo%20Shuo%20Wo%20Ai%20Ni.mp3

Comment: Even with the uploaded one my DirectShow has no problem. But I'm having installed K-Lite codec pack (whose codecs might have been used for playback). My system is up to date (all Windows updates applied).

Comment: What's the value of HR after the line of code with the call to RenderFile?

Comment: @Dave Nottage
Can't evaluate the value of HR, because at this stage the application is closed and immediately "I'm back in the IDE". There's no error thrown or anything else.

Comment: @Victoria

My system is also up to date. I don't have the K-Lite codec pack installed.
Maybe this "strange behavior" could be solved with the codec pack, but it doesn't solve the problem "at the root".
I would like to be able to "catch" this certain event to create a log file with the affected files. I rather would like to replace the "faulty" image. :-)

Comment: Use a library that bandles such files. You already have one.

Answer (score 0):

I got it managed now.
Only in debug mode the application/player is exited without any thrown error and I find myself back in the IDE.

During runtime the try...except block works, when I chose an "affected file" manually. For the case that one file is played ("good one") and the next file is a "bad one", I had to change my "MediaNext" procedure. In this procedure I also had a try...except block when the filename was associated to the TMediaPlayer, but I just had set a bool variable for further use and didn't "jump" to the next file.

The code just was:

```
try
  mplMain.FileName := CurrentSong;

except
  on E:Exception do
    SongNotPlayable := true;

end;
```

Here I can implement a routine to log the affected mp3 files into a logfile and then jump to the next file (if exists). :-)

Thanks again to all!